# How to create generic or global context in golang for new relic (Golang New relic integration)?

Tags: go, newrelic

I am creating new relic transaction in main.go and have to pass it along to handler and then to controller and so on. Is there a way i can define this globally and then can be accessed in any handler, controller or and db transaction?

```
import(
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    newrelic "github.com/newrelic/go-agent"
)

// main.go
func newrelicHandler() (gin.HandlerFunc, newrelic.Application) {
    newrelicConfig := newrelic.NewConfig("NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME", "NEW_RELIC_APP_KEY")
    app, err := newrelic.NewApplication(newrelicConfig)
    if err != nil {
        return func(c *gin.Context) {
            c.Next()
        }, app
    }
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        txn := app.StartTransaction(c.Request.URL.Path, c.Writer, c.Request)
        c.Set("newRelicTransaction", txn)
        apm, ok := c.Get("newRelicTransaction")
        defer txn.End()
        c.Next()
    }, app
}

func main() {
    r := gin.New()
    x, app := newrelicHandler()
    r.Use(x)
}


// test/handler.go

func (t *TestHandler) Display(c *gin.Context) {
    apmTxn, ok := c.Get("newRelicTransaction")

    test, err := t.testCtrl.Display(apmTxn)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"message": "success"})
}


// test/controller.go

func (t *TestCtrl) Display(txn interface{}) {
    apmTxn, ok := txn.(newrelic.Transaction)
    if !ok {
        fmt.Println("ERR")
    }
    segment := newrelic.StartSegment(apmTxn, "SomeSegmentName")
    // get data
    segment.End()
    return 
}
```

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67519598/how-to-capture-custom-error-message-in-new-relic-in-gin-gonic-and-nrgin/67524795#67524795

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid using a global context, rather create one at the entrypoint and then just pass it as an argument to any function that needs it.

You can make use of the `nrgin` package provided by the Gin framework.

And in the `main()` function

- Create an instance of newrelic - `newrelic.NewApplication(cfg)`
- Call the - `nrgin.Middleware(app)` function passing in the newrelic instance. This will add the Gin transaction context key - `newRelicTransaction` to the context.
- Register the function in step 2 as a middleware for all your routes - `router.Use(nrgin.Middleware(app))`

You can then pass this same context object to your other functions that can accept a parameter of type `context.Context` since `gin.Context` is simply implementing the `context` interface of Go.

Example code

```
import "github.com/newrelic/go-agent/_integrations/nrgin/v1"

func main() {
    cfg := newrelic.NewConfig("Gin App", mustGetEnv("NEW_RELIC_LICENSE_KEY"))
    
    app, err := newrelic.NewApplication(cfg)
    if nil != err {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    router := gin.Default()
    router.Use(nrgin.Middleware(app))

    router.GET("/example-get", GetController)

    router.Run(":80")
}

func GetController(c *gin.Context) {
    if txn := nrgin.Transaction(c); nil != txn {
        txn.SetName("custom-name")
    }

    databaseGet(c)

    c.Writer.WriteString("example response...")
}

func databaseGet(c context.Context) {
    if txn := nrgin.Transaction(c); nil != txn {
        txn.SetName("custom-name")
    }

    c.Writer.WriteString("example response...")
}
```

Comment: can i get the database query details also in new relic by using `nrgin.Transaction`? i am using gorm as ORM here for db queries.

Comment: GORM only supports Prometheus as of now - https://gorm.io/docs/prometheus.html ,its already been raised as an issue on GitHub to add support for NewRelic. Someone has posted a workaround for using NewRelic which you can try - https://github.com/newrelic/go-agent/issues/242#issuecomment-875706669